# What is the difference between Vec<i32> and Vec<Box<i32>>?

Tags: rust

```
let vec1 = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
let vec2 = vec![Box::new(1), Box::new(2), Box::new(3), Box::new(4)];
```

What is the difference between them?
I have already allocated vec1 on the heap. So aren't all the elements of vec1 also on the heap? Why would I need to separately allocate them on the heap like in vec2?

Comment: Not a rust expert here, but I think the difference is that `1` is the value 1, while `~1` is a owned pointer to 1. So in `vec2` you're just getting one more level of indirection

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I'll draw a diagram.  The first value is a pointer to a contiguous array of numbers on the heap.

```
(stack)    (heap)
┌──────┐   ┌───┐
│ vec1 │──→│ 1 │
└──────┘   ├───┤
           │ 2 │
           ├───┤
           │ 3 │
           ├───┤
           │ 4 │
           └───┘
```

The second version adds extra indirection.  The elements are still on the heap, but now they're *somewhere else* on the heap.

```
(stack)    (heap)   ┌───┐
┌──────┐   ┌───┐ ┌─→│ 1 │
│ vec2 │──→│   │─┘  └───┘
└──────┘   ├───┤    ┌───┐
           │   │───→│ 2 │
           ├───┤    └───┘
           │   │─┐  ┌───┐
           ├───┤ └─→│ 3 │
           │   │─┐  └───┘
           └───┘ │  ┌───┐
                 └─→│ 4 │
                    └───┘
```

Due to the way ownership works in Rust, you are not going to run into any semantic differences.  The extra indirection gives you worse memory usage and cache locality.

Comment: That's a really impressive diagram. How long did it take you to type it up?

Comment: Not very long, I just copy and paste box drawing characters around.

Answer (score 4):

`vec![1, 2, 3, 4]` is a vector of `i32`s.

`vec![Box::new(1), Box::new(2), Box::new(3), Box::new(4)]` is a vector of owned pointers to `i32`s. Rust's owned pointer is similar to C++'s unique_ptr.